# Timing behavior of null pointers in C

Tags: c

The below is mostly tested for Microsoft CL Version 17.00.50727.1 on Windows 7, but I see something similar with g++.  I'm quite sure that the logical function is correct.  The question is only about the timing.

Essentially I have a function that dynamically returns new "blocks" of data as needed.  If it runs out of space in its "page", it makes a new page.

The purpose of the blocks is to match incoming data keys.  If the key is found, that's great.  If not, then a new data key is added to the block.  If the block runs out of space, then a new block is created and linked to the old one.

The code works whether or not the block-making function explicitly sets the "next" pointer in the new block to NULL.  The theory is that calloc() has set the content to 0 already.

The first odd thing is that the block-making function takes about 5 times(!) longer to run when that "next" pointer is explicitly set to NULL.  However, then that is done, then the timing of the overall example behaves as expected:  It takes linearly longer to match a new key, the more entries there are in the key list.  The only difference occurs when a key is added which causes a new block to be fetched.  The overhead of doing that is similar to the time taken to call the block-making function.

The only problem with this is that the block-making function is unacceptably slow then.

When the pointer is NOT explicitly set to NULL, then the block-making function becomes nice and fast -- maybe half to a quarter of the key-matching function, instead of as long or even longer.

But then the key-matching function starts to exhibit odd timing behavior.  It does mostly increase linearly with the number of keys.  It still has jumps at 16 and 32 keys (since the list length is 16).  But it also has a large jump at key number 0, and it has large jumps at keys number 17, 33 etc.

These are the key numbers when the program first has to look at the "next" pointer.  Apparently it takes a long time to figure out that the 0 value from calloc is really a NULL pointer?  Once it knows this, the next times are faster.

The second weird thing is that the effect goes away if the data struct consists exclusively of the key.  Now the jumps at 0, 17, 33 etc. go away whether or not the "next" pointer is explicitly set to NULL.  But when "int unused[4]" is also in the struct, then the effect returns.

Maybe the compiler (with option /O2 or with -O3 for g++) optimizes away the struct when it consists of a single number?  But I still don't see why that would affect the timing behavior in this way.

I've tried to simplify the example as much as I could from the real code, but I'm sorry that it's still quite long.  It's not that complicated, though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

void timer_start(int n);
void timer_end(int n);
void print_times();

// There are pages of blocks, and data entries per block.
// We don't know ahead of time how many there will be.
// GetNextBlock() returns new blocks, and if necessary
// makes new pages.  MatchOrStore() goes through data in
// a block to try to match the key.  It won't ever match 
// in this example, so the function makes a new data entry.


struct dataType
{
  // Surprise number 1:  If the line with "unused" is
  // commented out, things behave as expected, even if
  // Surprise number 2 is in effect.
  int           unused[4];
  int           key;
};

#define DATA_PER_BLOCK  16

struct blockType
{
  char          nextEntryNo;
  struct dataType   list[DATA_PER_BLOCK];
  struct blockType  * next;
};

struct pageType
{
  int           nextBlockNo;
  struct blockType  * list;
  struct pageType   * next;
  struct pageType   * prev;
};


struct blockType * GetNextBlock();

void MatchOrStore(
  struct dataType   * dp,
  struct blockType  * bp);

struct pageType     * pagep;


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  pagep = (struct pageType *) 0;
  struct dataType data;

  for (int j = 0; j < 50000; j++)
  {
    struct blockType * blockp = GetNextBlock();
    // Make different keys each time.
    for (data.key = 0; data.key < 40; data.key++)
    {
      // One timer per key number, useful for statistics.
      timer_start(data.key);
      MatchOrStore(&data, blockp);
      timer_end(data.key);
    }
  }

  print_times();
  exit(0);
}


#define BLOCKS_PER_PAGE 5000

struct blockType * GetNextBlock()
{
  if (pagep == NULL || 
      pagep->nextBlockNo == BLOCKS_PER_PAGE)
  {
    // If this runs out of page space, it makes some more.
    struct pageType * newpagep = (struct pageType *)
      calloc(1, sizeof(struct pageType));

    newpagep->list = (struct blockType *)
      calloc(BLOCKS_PER_PAGE, sizeof(struct blockType));

    // I never actually free this, but you get the idea.
    newpagep->nextBlockNo = 0;
    newpagep->next        = NULL;
    newpagep->prev        = pagep;

    if (pagep)
      pagep->next = newpagep;
    pagep = newpagep;
  }

  struct blockType * bp = &pagep->list[ pagep->nextBlockNo++ ];

  // Surprise number 2:  If this line is active, then the
  // timing behaves as expected.  If it is commented out,
  // then presumably calloc still sets next to NULL.
  // But the timing changes in an unexpected way.
  // bp->next = (struct blockType *) 0;

  return bp;
}


void MatchOrStore(
  struct dataType   * dp,
  struct blockType  * blockp)
{
  struct blockType * bp = blockp;

  while (1)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < bp->nextEntryNo; i++)
    {
      // This will spend some time traversing the list of
      // blocks, failing to find the key, because that's
      // the way I've set up the data for this example.
      if (bp->list[i].key != dp->key) continue;
      // It will never match.
      return;
    }
    if (! bp->next) break;
    bp = bp->next;
  }

  if (bp->nextEntryNo == DATA_PER_BLOCK)
  {
    // Once in a while it will run out of space, so it
    // will make a new block and add it to the list.
    timer_start(99);
    struct blockType * bptemp = GetNextBlock();
    bp->next = bptemp;
    bp       = bptemp;
    timer_end(99);
  }

  // Since it didn't find the key, it will store the key
  // in the list here.
  bp->list[ bp->nextEntryNo++ ].key = dp->key;
}

#define NUM_TIMERS 100

#ifdef _WIN32
  #include <time.h>
  LARGE_INTEGER 
    tu0[NUM_TIMERS], 
    tu1[NUM_TIMERS];
#else
  #include <sys/time.h>
  struct timeval
    tu0[NUM_TIMERS], 
    tu1[NUM_TIMERS];
#endif

int ctu[NUM_TIMERS],
    number[NUM_TIMERS];


void timer_start(int no)
{
  number[no]++;
#ifdef _WIN32
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&tu0[no]);
#else
  gettimeofday(&tu0[no], NULL);
#endif
}


void timer_end(int no)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&tu1[no]);
  ctu[no] += (tu1[no].QuadPart - tu0[no].QuadPart);
#else
  gettimeofday(&tu1[no], NULL);
  ctu[no] += 1000000 * (tu1[no].tv_sec  - tu0[no].tv_sec )
              +        (tu1[no].tv_usec - tu0[no].tv_usec);
#endif
}


void print_times()
{
  printf("%5s  %10s  %10s  %8s\n",
    "n", "Number", "User ticks", "Avg");

  for (int n = 0; n < NUM_TIMERS; n++)
  {
    if (number[n] == 0)
      continue;

    printf("%5d  %10d  %10d  %8.2f\n",
      n, 
      number[n],
      ctu[n],
      ctu[n] / (double) number[n]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is tagged as C but is C++ code.

Comment: @ouah, this looks like C99 to me. What makes you say it's C++?

Comment: @davmac `typedef dataType dataType` instead of `typedef struct dataType dataType`

Comment: Hmm. It is using C idioms, the only C++ seems to be this `typedef` issue. @user3139990 could you either fix your code or re-tag?

Comment: How slow? Is this at the level of cache misses and pipeline stalls? Have you checked the generated code?

Comment: Certainly.  There are no more typedefs now.  It should be vanilla C.

Comment: @david.pfx I don't know how to answer that.  No ability/experience.  In terms of time per invocation, the whole MatchOrStore function gets 5-6 times slower when "next" is set explicitly (and when adding the 17th or 33rd element), and that function does a fair amount of work.  Similar ratio for GetNextBlock alone.

Comment: are you building in Release mode with max optimization?

Comment: you're missing `#include <stdlib.h>`, required for calloc

Comment: @MattMcNabb It's being compiled from the command line with "cl /O2" which I think is the highest optimization level for Microsoft's "cl" compiler.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I've added #include <stdlib.h> even though the "cl" compiler doesn't ask for it.  Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not what it claims to be about - it's *not* about the behavior of null pointers. It is about code generation in a particular, not quite well minimized code snippet. Yet there's no compiler output in sight, and the problem seems to be too localized to be of use to anyone else.

Comment: I'm happy to retag, retitle etc. if someone will actually help me.  I spent a day reducing the problem as far as I could from a much larger piece of code from someone else.  It looked like c99 to me, and I'm sorry I was not aware of the differences.  The current code can be compiled with "gcc -O3 -std=c99 test.c -o test" and exhibits an anomalous time consumption for the very first key, depending on whether or not "next" is set.  The effects are different in "cl", which I now realize is considering it C++ code and doesn't support c99.  I will rewrite to old C if needed to get an answer.

Comment: @user3139990: This is a site for good questions and good answers, not just "please debug my code". You need to strip this code to the minimum; make sure it compiles in C (if that's the aim); present the actual timing numbers; show the generated code (if relevant); fix the title and/or tags. There is something interesting going on here, but you're not giving us what we need to work out what.

Comment: @david.pfx Thanks.  Is it most appropriate then to somehow close this question and make a new one, once I have accomplished what you ask?  Or to edit this one heavily?  It IS indeed about pointers in structs and their different timing behavior if calloc'ed to zero or NULLed explicitly.  The questions always stop after "Do they behave the same?"  "Yes, on all modern machines, but..."

Comment: If the code is different, probably a new question.